# Numerical solution for the Mukhanov-Sasaki equation with Bunch-Davies vacuum state

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, astrophysics, universe, cosmological-inflation

I have the Mukhanov-Sasaki equation in terms of $u_k$

\begin{align*}
u''_k(\tau)+\left(k^2-\frac{a''(\tau)}{a(\tau)}+f(\tau)\right)u_k(\tau)=0
\end{align*}

and also the initial condition from Bunch-Davies

\begin{align*}
u_k(\tau)=\lim_{k>>aH}\frac{e^{-ik\tau}}{\sqrt{2k}}
\end{align*}

How do I choose proper values for $\tau$ and $k$? I know they have to be deep in the horizon, but $\tau$ has to be the one connected to $k$? I'm working with the Starobinsky model

\begin{align*}
V(\phi)=3/4\left(1-e^{-\sqrt{2/3}\phi(t)}\right)^2
\end{align*}

Equations with $c=h=G=M_P=1$. Or how is it possible to compute the solutions using NDSolve from Mathematica? I've already posted many questions and haven't received any help.

Comment: *I've already posted many questions and haven't received any help.* I suspect it is because what you're looking for is very niche which means that very few people are familiar with it. You may want to consult with your advisor or instructor for assistance.